# Makefile conditional statements

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Scenario :

Consider a source directory which has multiple ".cpp" files that creates a static library
consider files: XYZ.cpp & ABC.cpp (used specificly based on condition described below ) as well as PQR.cpp, JKL.cpp etc.., output library name is out.a

Here p ( is an environment variable) whose value if matches to q then,
out.a should be created using XYZ.cpp else it should be created using ABC.cpp

Ex:  i.e. something like this

```
ifeq($p, q)
SRC = XYZ.cpp
else
SRC = ABC.cpp
endif
SRC += PQR.cpp \
       JKL.cpp \
       MNO.cpp
```

How could I do the same optimizely in Makefile ?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost exactly it. You just need a space after `ifeq`, (and some parentheses around `p`, in case you want to use a variable name longer than one letter):

```
ifeq ($(p), q)
SRC = XYZ.cpp
else
SRC = ABC.cpp
endif
SRC += PQR.cpp \
       JKL.cpp \
       MNO.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Beta's answer is quite correct, you might alternatively consider constructed variable names.  In my opinion, they lead to cleaner and more readable makefiles.  For example:

```
# if p is not set, default to "default"
p ?= default

q_SRC = XYZ.cpp
default_SRC = ABC.cpp

SRC = $($(p)_SRC) PQR.cpp JKL.cpp MNO.cpp
```

etc.  Especially if you have lots of alternatives this can be much more understandable (again, IMO).

Comment: However, this runs the risk of breaking if, for example, I do `make p=xyz`, where the `if ... else ...` construct would at least still assign some sort of default, even if it's not the right one...

Comment: You can use `ifeq ($($(p)_SRC),)` to see if the value has been set; if not then you know it was set to something bogus.  You can either use a default, or else `$(error ...)`.

Comment: This could also be possible but In my case p would not be set for file name. Still Thanks I could understand what you wants to convey.